# BottomNavigation doesn't work after switching Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

Im new to Android Studio and currently working on my first App.
I have started by adding the BottomNavigationActivity provided by Android Studio.
The Fragments should display a List of items, which can be added via a Button (this opens a new Fragment where new Items can be created and added to the list by clicking a Button -> this brings the User back to the List)
My Problem is, that after I clicked the Button to add an Item, my Navbar stops working.
This is the Message i am getting:
I/FragmentNavigator: Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state

I have 2 Navigation files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_kalender">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_habits"
        android:name="com.example.bottomtest.ui.habits.HabitsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_habits"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_habits" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_kalender"
        android:name="com.example.bottomtest.ui.kalender.KalenderFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_kalender"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_kalender" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notizen"
        android:name="com.example.bottomtest.ui.notizen.NotizenFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notizen"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notizen" />
</navigation>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/notizen_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/notizenFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/notizenBearbeitenFragment"
        android:name="com.example.bottomtest.ui.notizen.NotizenBearbeitenFragment"
        android:label="fragment_notizen_bearbeiten"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notizen_bearbeiten" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_notizenBearbeitenFragment_to_notizenFragment"
            app:destination="@id/notizenFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/notizenFragment"
        android:name="com.example.bottomtest.ui.notizen.NotizenFragment"
        android:label="fragment_notizen"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notizen" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_notizenFragment_to_notizenBearbeitenFragment"
            app:destination="@id/notizenBearbeitenFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

This is my MainActivity OnCreate:

```
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_habits, R.id.navigation_kalender, R.id.navigation_notizen)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }
```

And this is my OnViewCreated in the Fragments:

```
        binding.newNoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NotizenBearbeitenFragment notizenBearbeitenFragment = new NotizenBearbeitenFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container, notizenBearbeitenFragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

Im sorry if this is a dumb question but i can't find a solution by myself, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a manual `FragmentTransaction`? That's never how you [navigate to a new screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate).

Answer (score 0):

Do not touch the FragmentManager yourself when using the Navigation library.

Let [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) manage Navigation between fragments, that's what it's used for.

The message:

> I/FragmentNavigator: Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has
> already saved its state

is defined in the `androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator#navigate`
The Fragment state is saved by the Activity. It usually appears when the Activity goes into the onStop state. Means should not be operated the fragmentManger after leaving the current Activity. (but still can use `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction#commitAllowingStateLoss` to ignore the warning , but this state will not be restored when the Activity is recreated.)

In your scenes, I recommend jumping to the next activity for editing, returning and refreshing the list